# Entity Framework, no tt file but want to change ICollection

Tags: entity-framework, observablecollection, t4, icollection

Having discovered that I can, by hand, create a db table and a corresponding class, a context etc and all 'just works' without any VS EF wizardry whatsoever, this is how I have been using EF for some time. In my situation, I don't want/need code generation.

But, I am now wondering how to change the ICollection to, say, ObservableCollection in the model, without having to do "new ObservableCollection()" in a repository.

Most references to this issue refer to the TT file and describe how to change ICollection to something else. As I have no TT file, this is not possible. So how can I get EF to populate something other than ICollection?

Comment: You have your own class which contains `ICollection<AnotherClass>` property and you want to change `ICollection` to something else - `List`, `HashSet`, `ObservableCollection`, basically any class that implements `ICollection<T>` and has parameterless constructor. So simply change the collection type in your class. I don't understand what's the issue.

Comment: Yes, apologies, my mistake (a missing .Include()). Still, advice on numerous issues is to edit the tt file, but I guess it contains no magic and the same problems can always (?) be solved by direct edit of classes/annotations, context or schema.